# How to format a float point number in python?

Tags: python

I have a number 15.579. I want to format it to write 0.15790000E+02. 
I can display it as 1.57900000E+01 but I want a 0 before the decimal point.
How can I do it in Python?

Comment: @ChandaKorat: That "possible duplicate" wants standard scientific notation, while this one wants a non-standard form where the significand (mantissa) is between 0.1 and 1. So this is not a duplicate--though this question may have other problems.

Comment: Thanks Rory for understanding the question. Please, can you help me out with this?

Comment: How many decimal places do you want to show? Will that be consistent or do you want it as a parameter? And I need to go now and will not be able to answer until this afternoon (7 hours from now).

Comment: Ohk my bad. Removed.

Comment: The number of decimal places is a constant, it's just that it should have a zero before the decimal point and the significant digits should start right after the decimal point. Please reply whenever you are free.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. This checks for negative numbers and for any weird result. I also used Python's default precision, and made that as well as the decimal point character changeable. You can easily change the default precision if you want 8 digits, as in your example, but Python's default is 6.

```
def alt_sci_notation(x, prec=6, decpt='.'):
    """Return a string of a floating point number formatted in
    alternate scientific notation. The significand (mantissa) is to be
    between 0.1 and 1, not including 1--i.e. the decimal point is
    before the first digit. The number of digits after the decimal
    point, which is also the number of significant digits, is 6 by
    default and must be a positive integer. The decimal point character
    can also be changed.
    """
    # Get regular scientific notation with the new exponent
    s = '{0:.{p}E}'.format(10 * x, p=prec-1)
    # Handle negative values
    prefix = ''
    if s[0] == '-':
        prefix = s[0]
        s = s[1:]
    # Return the string after moving the decimal point
    if prec > 1:  # if a decimal point exists in thesignificand
        return prefix + '0' + decpt + s[0] + s[2:]
    else:  # no decimal point, just one digit in the significand
        return prefix + '0' + decpt + s
```

Here are sample results in iPython.

```
alt_sci_notation(15.579, 8)
Out[2]: '0.15579000E+02'

alt_sci_notation(-15.579, 8)
Out[3]: '-0.15579000E+02'

alt_sci_notation(0)
Out[4]: '0.000000E+00'

alt_sci_notation(100000000)
Out[5]: '0.100000E+09'

alt_sci_notation(.00000001)
Out[6]: '0.100000E-07'
```